# How to access a database through the internet (+ Ionic and PouchDB)

Tags: couchdb, remote-access, remote-server, ionic3, pouchdb

TLDR: How do I setup a computer with CouchDB so that I can access it remotely with another computer through the internet?

I'm trying to teach myself how to build an app that stores data on a remote server. I try it using Ionic 3.x to build the app, CouchDB as the remote database and PouchDB on the device.
I've managed to get the app and the databases working, when I set up CouchDB as localhost. Now I installed CouchDB on my other computer (2) and try to access it from the one I currently use (1).
On the other computer (2) I downloaded and installed CouchDB. Then I verified it and created an admin. Then I created a database with one document containing the string "hello" for testing purposes. I configured the bind_adress to be "0.0.0.0". I also enabled CORS for all domains (*) on (2).

When I now try to get the data (with (1)) from the the other computer (2) over the internet using "curl -X GET http://[IPGOESHERE]/[DBNAME]/_all_docs" the command never finishes. Apparently it doesn't get an answer (?). I tried both, using my IP4 and my public IP. Both didn't work.

How can access the CouchDB remotely through the internet? Am I missing some settings?

Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: did you change the port to 80? Otherwise it's ..[IP]:5984/[DB]/...

Comment: With this sort of problem it is best to start at the beginning and try to Telnet to the address/port on the server to make sure it can be reached from your computer. Could you try to do this and let us know what happens please?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the default port 5984 for accessing CouchDB:

```
http://[IPGOESHERE]:5984/[DBNAME]/_all_docs
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like more of networking issue rather than couchdb settings itself. Are you able to ping to the remote pc on which couchdb is installed???